# How come I can't get Django to talk to this library?

Tags: python, database, django, caching, redis

I want to use Redis. So I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache

First, I install redis-py: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/

Then, I put this in my settings: `CACHE_BACKEND = 'redis_cache.cache://localhost:6379'`

Then I do this in my views.py:

```
from redis_cache import cache #this imports just fine!
cache.set("haha","lala")
print cache.get("haha")
```

But for some reason,  I get an AttributeError:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'set'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to import Django's cache module (the abstraction layer that calls Redis eventually) instead of directly using Redis:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```